# Django views- How to translate info messages in HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-views

I want to translate a message in HttpResponseRedirect() to german.I have a pop box in my website.which displays the information .the information is given by HttpResonseRedirect declared in views.I have to translate that information..the code goes like this::

if frmChangePassword.is_valid():
                try:
                    password1 = frmChangePassword.cleaned_data['password1']
                    password2 = frmChangePassword.cleaned_data['password2']

```
                if password1 == password2:
                    oe = OEConnector()
                    UpdatePasswordData= oe.updateData('res.users',[request.session['user_id']],{'password':password1})
                    if UpdatePasswordData:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Info?info=Password changed successfully.')
                    else:
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Info?info=Unable to update password. The following error occured -> ' + e.__str__())
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/Info?info=Passwords you provided did not match.')

            except Exception as e:
                 return HttpResponseRedirect('/Info?info=Unable to update password. The following error occured -> ' + e.__str__())
    elif request.POST['action'] == "newsletter_update":
        #Check if newsletter_active checkbox has been checked
        #If not, then seeking this value will throw an error
        try:
            request.POST['newsletter_active'] 
        except:
            newsletter_status = False
        else:
            newsletter_status = True
        oe = OEConnector()
        UpdateNewsletterData= oe.updateData('res.partner.address',[request.session['partner_id']],{'newsletter_subs':newsletter_status})
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Info?info=Newsletter updated successfully.') .
```

How can i translate the messages in HttpResponseRedirect...I know bout gettext,trans ,blocktrans,inlinetrans.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going the wrong way, by trying to pass you message through a GET parameter like that. Use a [django messages framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/):

```
from django.contrib import messages
if password1 == password2:
    oe = OEConnector()
    UpdatePasswordData= oe.updateData('res.users',[request.session['user_id']],{'password':password1})
    if UpdatePasswordData:
        messages.success(_('Password changed successfully.'))
    else:
        messages.error(_('Unable to update password. The following error occured -> ') + e.__str__())
else:
    messages.error(_('Passwords you provided did not match.'))
return HttpResponseRedirect('/Info')
```

And then you can print messages in your template giving error and success messages different CSS style:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Try the messages framework, it will make try coding times easier. And of course, there is no problem translating the messages.

Comment: You said "And of course, there is no problem translating the messages". I have trouble translating my messages. Would you mind explaining? I'm adding a `messages.success(request, 'sign-up-success')` in my view, and `{% blocktrans %}{{ message }}{% endblocktrans %} won't work after I change the .po file. I concluded Django can't translate variables...

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is to have proper order in middleware in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    )
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#how-to-create-language-files